# Uso de Switch en java

Tags: java

Soy muy nuevo, estoya aprendiendo, necesito ayuda con la estructura de un condicional, a la hora de ingresar un valor debe ser ese valor y si no es que se devuelva a la pregunta hasta que se digite bien, el codigo que llevo es:

```
package principal;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import javax.swing.JLabel;
//import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Vista extends JFrame{

    boolean jornada = false;

    public Vista() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nom_estudiante = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nombre del estudiante: ");
        String nom_carrera = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nombre de la carrera: ");

        try {
            int valor_mat = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el valor de la matricula"));
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Los datos deben ser enteros: ");
        }
//        switch() {
//            case 1:
//                
//        }       
//        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,valor_mat);
//        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,nom_estudiante);
//        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,nom_carrera);    
    }


    public void matricula1(){


    }
}
```

El problema es que hasta que no se digite bien la matricula que debe ser de 980 no puede pasar a hacer el codigo respectivo, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: esa parte creo que quedaría mejor si usa un ciclo for, que el switch, ya que el switc, si no encuentra algun valor de los que tiene programados simplemente deja de funcionar y lo tienes que ejecutar otra vez, o a lo mejor encierra el switch en un ciclo for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar un switch utiliza un do-while y encierra tu estructura try catch dentro de ese ciclo,  algo como esto:

```
 boolean valorIngresadoValido = false;
 do{

    try {

        int valor_mat = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el valor de la matricula"));
        valorIngresadoValido = true;

    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Los datos deben ser enteros: ");
    }

 }while(!valorIngresadoValido);
```

De esta manera se repetira el ciclo siempre que el usuario coloque algo que no sea un numero,  y cuando no haya algun error (que el usuario haya efectivamente introducido un numero,  hacemos un break de manera manual (quice hacerlo asi como para usar la variavle valorIngresadoValido), sin embargo si quieres pones al final de lo que este dentro del try un break,  notese que muy probablemente la respuesta no este correctamente formateada debido a que la hice en el cel.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso un switch no es la mejor manera, yo te recomendaria usar un if o un ciclo while.
Una respuesta a tu problema usando switch seria usando recursividad, que para no enredarte mucho la cabeza en conceptos técnicos ya que estas comenzando significa volver a repetir todo el método, ¿como se hace? simplemente llamas al método y en tu caso el seguirá ejecutando tú método hasta que cumpla con el switch, cualquiera duda escríbeme un comentario.

```
public void vista() {

        String nom_estudiante = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nombre del estudiante: ");
        String nom_carrera = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el nombre de la carrera: ");
        int valor_mat=0;

        try { 
             valor_mat = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba el valor de la matricula"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos deben ser enteros: "); // aqui es mejor un message ya que no vas a ingresar nada solo es para advertir
        }


        switch(valor_mat){

            case 980: System.out.println("Si escribio el 980");// en este caso recibe el valor esperando aqui iria todo el código que tu quieres que suceda cuando se cumpla el caso
            // pero como te digo no es la mejor manera
            break; // le decimos que termina con el switch ya que cumplimos la condición

            default: System.out.println("Ingreso un valor diferente a 980"); // default que vendria siendo si no se cumple ninguno caso anterior
            vista();// ENTONCES ejecuta el metodo otra vez

        }

    }
```